from . import _AWS, ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Installed mingrammer diagram by
pip install diagram

 __init__.py

from diagrams import Node


class _AWS(Node):
    _provider = "aws"
    _icon_dir = "resources/aws"

    fontcolor = "#ffffff"

compute.py
from . import _AWS


class _Compute(_AWS):
    _type = "compute"
    _icon_dir = "resources/aws/compute"


class AppRunner(_Compute):
    _icon = "app-runner.png"

I run compute.py, but I am getting error like this
need your help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ravim\OneDrive\Desktop\mypython\mingrammer-diagrams\aws\compute.py", line 3, in <module>    
    from . import _AWS
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

